# Safari uses wrong web font weight on some computers

Tags: css, fonts, safari, webfonts

This is a pretty weird issue so I'd welcome even a hint as to where to start looking.  I'm helping edit some Sass right now, and we recently added a web font to the page.  The typeface is Sofia Pro, and I added `@font-face` declarations for six different fonts: Light, Regular, and Black, and an italic version of each.  The `@font-face` rules all use the same `font-family` ('Sofia Pro') but declare different weights and styles for each so we can use Sofia more naturally in our styles.  The Light font is weight 300, the Regular is 400, and the Black is 900.

Here's the problem:

In all other browsers, and in Safari on my computer, page elements that are styled with `font-weight: bold` (a synonym for 700) correctly use the next-darker available weight, the Sofia Pro Black font with weight 900.  On my coworker's computer though, Safari seems to be using Sofia Pro Regular for these elements.  If we change the element styles in his inspector to instead use `font-weight: 900` they correctly use Sofia Pro Black, so the web font is loaded and accessible, but for some reason his browser seems to behave directly counter to the CSS spec with respect to the `font-weight` property, whereas mine is behaving correctly.

We're both on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 and we're both using Safari version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34).  It's easy enough to change all the bold elements to use weight 900 instead so that it displays correctly for both of us --
 that's not really the point.  The point is, we're at a loss as to what could be causing this difference in behavior, and it's a pretty concerning difference for a web developer.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not even sure this is on topic here since I can't think of how the code itself could be causing the problem--but then I'm not sure how two instances of the same browser version could be causing the issue either, so who knows?  It certainly pertains to our development environment!  I'm currently at a loss